# what's wrong with this async wireup of an axios get()?

Tags: reactjs

I had a function in my React component which encapsulated an axios call to return supporting data.  I created a new component named ApiFacade to encapsulate axios calls.  I'm trying to call a function to return data from a function in ApiFacade to the main component.  Here's the code where I'm calling the function in ApiFacade:

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const suppliers = await ApiFacade.getSuppliersDropdownData();
    debugger;
}
```

Here's the function in ApiFacade:

```
static async getSuppliersDropdownData(){
    let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true
        }
      }

    const url = apiFacadeConfig.baseUrl + "suppliers-dropdown";
    axios.get(url, axiosConfig)
      .then(function(response){
          let suppliers = response.data[0];
          let defaultSupplier = [{ SupplierId:0, ContactFirstName:''}];
          suppliers = [...defaultSupplier, ...suppliers];
          return suppliers;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          alert('bubble: ' + error.message);
      });
```

The ApiFacade function is getting called without error.  The control flow enters into the then() block indicating success, and the catch block does not get entered.  The "suppliers" variable gets populated with data as expected.  The problem is that suppliers shows as "undefined" on the line after the ApiFacade function call in componentDidMount().  Then the CDT debugger hits a breakpoint within the ApiFacade function call.  What do I need to change with this implementation so that suppliers gets returned to the call from componentDidMount() in the expected sequence?

Comment: You don't return the promise chain from the facade.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

```
return axios.get(url, axiosConfig)
```

instead of

```
axios.get(url, axiosConfig)
```

in `getSuppliersDropdownData()`